# Lab equipment - where to start

Tags: experimental-physics, soft-question

I've started to seriously study physics on my own, using various resources such as edX courses etc. However I believe that carrying out experiments will help me gain a deeper understanding of the concepts in textbooks, but I don't know what I should buy.

Firstly, what is the best website to buy physics equipment? I live in the Middle East, so international shipping is required (in most cases).

Secondly, I want to be able to carry out as many experiments as possible on different topics of physics (especially Mechanics and Electromagnetism), so could anyone recommend a collection of things I should buy?

Thirdly, I am currently in highschool and I'm prepared to spend around 300 dollars.

Thank you.

Comment: There are [many commercial kits](https://www.a3bs.com/advanced-student-experiment-kits,pg_779.html), but for mechanics you just need stuff you can find in your home and garage - build a pendulum, use a bicycle wheel, a few coins.  For basic electricity you can replicate Ben Franklin with styrofoam, but a kit is a better starting point for electronics.

Comment: You already have the best piece of equipment: your computer. Learn how to interface it to the world (e.g. with something like this: http://www.dataq.com/products/di-149) and how to analyze data with it. I would stay away from physics kits, they are usually too specialized to teach you anything. In general: if you need something, get REAL equipment for cheap, i.e. surplus and used items. Learn how to make an experiment ever more precise. Learn how to identify and analyze systematic and experimental errors. If you have clear skies... learn to make astronomical observations!